# Алгоритм судоку

Tags: c, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Есть такой код, вывод я тут написал сам, но саму логику `trycell` я нашёл в интернете и совсем не понимаю, как это работает. Как это работает и при каком условии рекурсия продолжает работать? Зачем тут используют побитовые сдвиги и побитовые или?

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char letter)
{
    write(1, &letter, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        ft_putchar(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int     length_itr(int n)
{
    int out;

    out = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        out++;
    }
    return (out);
}

void    ft_put_positive(int nb)
{
    if (nb != 0)
    {
        ft_put_positive(nb / 10);
        ft_putchar(nb % 10 + '0');
    }
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb == 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('0');
    }
    else if (nb > 0)
    {
        ft_put_positive(nb);
    }
}

void    printf_d(int n, int space)
{
    int i;
    int length;

    length = length_itr(n);

    i = length;
    while (i < space)
    {
        ft_putchar(' ');
        i++;
    }
    ft_putnbr(n);
}

void    show(int *x)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (i++ < 9) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 9)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                printf_d(*x++, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf_d(*x++, 2);
            }
            j++;
        }
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
}

int     trycell(int *x, int pos)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int i;
    int j;
    int used;

    row = pos / 9;
    col = pos % 9;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    used = 0;

    if (pos == 81)
    {
        return (1);
    }
    if (x[pos])
    {
        return (trycell(x, pos + 1));
    }


    while (i < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + col] - 1);
        i++;
    }

    while (j < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[row * 9 + j] - 1);
        j++;
    }

    row = row / 3 * 3;
    col = col / 3 * 3;
    i = row;
    while (i < row + 3)
    {
        j = col;
        while (j < col + 3)
        {
            used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + j] - 1);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    x[pos] = 1;
    while (x[pos] <= 9)
    {
        if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1)) return 1;
        used >>= 1;
        x[pos]++;
    }

    x[pos] = 0;
    return 0;
}

void    solve(const char *s)
{
    int i;
    int x[81];

    while (i < 81)
    {
        if (s[i] >= '1' && s[i] <= '9')
        {
            x[i] = s[i] - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            x[i] = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (trycell(x, 0))
    {
        show(x);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putstr("no solution");
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
  solve(  "........."
        "........."
        ".98....6."
        "8...6...3"
        "4..8.3..1"
        "7...2...6"
        ".6....28."
        "...419..5"
        "....8..79" );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: У меня есть судоку. Я храню числа в двумерном массиве. А тут какой-то жестяк. Но щас попробую разобраться...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика решателя не слишком сложная: мы создаём "итераторы" на всех ячейках и пробуем подставлять значения до тех пор, пока последний итератор не сможет тоже его подставить. Итераторы на подсказках(константах) не работают.

Рекурсия продолжается, пока очередному итератору не попадётся позиция 81 (когда надо от 0 до 80):

```
if (pos == 81)
{
    return (1);
}
```

Ну а дальше всё по канону.
Если значение на позиции итератора уже подставлено - слово передаётся следующему за ним итератору:

```
if (x[pos])
{
    return (trycell(x, pos + 1));
}
```

used - это, как я понимаю, битовая маска, которая показывает какие числа уже были использованы в ряде, столбце и в квадрате, к которым относится данная ячейка:

```
 while (i < 9)
{
    used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + col] - 1);
    i++;
}

while (j < 9)
{
    used |= 1 << (x[row * 9 + j] - 1);
    j++;
}

row = row / 3 * 3;
col = col / 3 * 3;
i = row;
while (i < row + 3)
{
    j = col;
    while (j < col + 3)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + j] - 1);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Теперь нам известно какие числа подставлять не надо. Переходим к главному - пробуем подставлять:

```
x[pos] = 1;
while (x[pos] <= 9)
{
    if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1)) return 1;
    used >>= 1;
    x[pos]++;
}

x[pos] = 0;
return 0;
```

То есть начинаем с единицы, а дальше просто проверяем, смогли ли заполнится ячейки за текущей! Если смогли - вылетаем с ответом 1, а если нет - очищаем ячейку и возвращаем 0.

Если честно, этот код нуждается в рефакторинге. Выглядит рабочим, но ужасно читается.

Ещё мне не нравится, что автор считает used для ячейки пробегая по всем строкам, столбцам, квадратам, когда можно потратить чуть больше памяти и хранить used для каждого столбца, квадрата, и строки в дополнительных массивах. И конечно же значения этих used должно обновляться всякий раз, когда кто-либо изменяет значение ячейки. Ну и в итераторе потом просто складываются три значения через побитовый ИЛИ.

Comment: А вы понимаете как мне сделать ошибку при больше [1 решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080109/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-1-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)?

Comment: Да. Было дело, число решений считал) Ну и ошибку выдать не трудно, думаю!

Comment: К сожалению, я не понимаю как это всё сравнение происходит

Comment: Ну, я объяснил всё, что понимаю сам и так, как я это понимаю.